# How reclaim a bricked USB stick

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

I used the USB Stick formatter on a linux system to format a USB stick (Kingston DataTraveler). Everything appeared to succeed, but now when I plug it in, it no longer is recognized. I've tried multiple computers.

It shows up in `dmesg`:

```
[14453.736097] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[14454.055962] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[14454.171292] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666
[14454.171300] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[14454.171303] usb 4-2: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[14454.171306] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Kingston
[14454.171309] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: D850E64A7E2ABF51097513CB
[14454.172000] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
```

And in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 008: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler G4
```

but not in `sudo fdisk -l`, which only shows my hard drive. Everything else I've been able to find has a USB stick showing up in `fdisk` -- then I know how to reformat using `gparted` or whatever; but in this case, it doesn't show up in `gparted`.

The output from /var/log/syslog is:

```
[  391.878840] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  392.362503] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  392.477527] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666
[  392.477535] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  392.477539] usb 4-1: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[  392.477543] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[  392.477545] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: D850E64A7E2ABF51097513CB
[  392.478178] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  392.478495] scsi8 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
Latitude-E6430 mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-1"
Latitude-E6430 mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 4 was not an MTP device
[  414.274366] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  419.283362] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  419.387118] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  424.396823] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  424.557108] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  424.557427] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88021f6a89c0
[  424.557430] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88021f6a8a08
```

But it's not completely dead because it shows up in `dmesg` and `lsusb` -- so, what is wrong?

Comment: It could be the storage that is dead but not the controller, or neither is dead but just they lost contact with each other because stuff in between is fried.

Comment: And running it through a stick formatter like that could do this? It's a fairly new drive. Any way to solve it? Or is it just trash at this point?

Comment: I don't really know about this `USB Stick formatter` but it's unlikely that a program can physically damage a USB flash drive. It could be just coincidence. You may want to try it on another computer before trashing it though. Btw, do you see `No medium found` (for `sdb`, for example, assuming the system drive is the only connected drive apart from this flash drive) in dmesg?

Comment: I'd try a different low-level formatting utility, ideally one provided by the flash drive manufacturer.

Comment: What is "the USB Stick formatter" anyway? Was the drive working 100% perfect (linux and windows) before you "formatted" it?

Comment: In Mint there is a tool called, literally, "USB Stick Formatter". It had been working 100% before that, linux and windows.